# Making table cells clickable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I currently have a table of about 30 rows and I would like to make `<td>` clickable in each case:

```
<tr height="100px" align="center">        
        <?php do { ?>
        <td style="background-color: <?php echo $row_dd1['colour']; ?>;">   
        <form action="pay.php?id=<?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?>&user=<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?>"><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
          <button type="submit" class="link" id="t<?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?>"><span><?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?></span></button></form>
        </td>
        <?php } while ($row_dd1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dd1)); ?>
    </tr>
```

How do you make the table cell clickable? I would like it to have the same link as the form action that I have used which is:

```
<form action="pay.php?id=<?php echo $row_dd1['dNo']; ?>&user=<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect example of where to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), like this:

```
$("#myTableID").delegate("td", "click", function() {
  $(this).find("form").submit();
});
```

[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) attaches *one* handler to the `<table>`, rather than `n` handlers, one per cell.  If you just want to navigate to the URL, it would look like:

```
$("#myTableID").delegate("td", "click", function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).find("form").attr("action");
});
```

Comment: Nice one! Didn't think of that. +1!

Answer (score 1):

What about jQuery's [click-event](http://api.jquery.com/click/)?

```
$('td').click(function () {
    $('form', this).submit();
    return false;
});
```

This submits the form inside the clicked `<td>`.

Answer (score 1):

To actually submit the form:

```
$('td > form').each(function(i,e){
   var form = $(this);
   var cell = form.parent();
   if(cell.is('td')){
     cell.click(function(){
       form.submit();
     });
   }
});
```

If you jsut want to follow the link instead, jsut modify the `form.submit()` part to change `window.location.href` with `form.attr('action')`.